# xcode run script on deployment

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, xcode4.5

I have a game which has xml files in it. My game works on iPad and on iPhone, and i need to perform some changes in these xml files accordingly, but the xml files are original and i do not want them changed, so what i want is have my xml files changed automatically at compile time. For this purpose i have a ruby script which does what i need.
Let's say this script is level_converter.rb
which i can execute(in terminal) as follows:

```
for f in Resources/*.xml; do ruby level_converter.rb "$f"; done
```

So i added this code to Build Phases to Run Script this way and this does work as expected, it does change all the xml files properly, BUT ofcourse it changes the original xml files in the resources foler. So say if i run twice - i'll have these files changed twice. What i want is these files stay not changed but only those deployed should change. So i need some kind of $(PROJECT_DISTRIBUTION_AND_DEVELOPEMENT_TEMP_FOLDER) or something like that instead of simply Resorces/*.xml eg.

```
for f in $(PROJ_DISTRIB_AND_DEV_TMP_FLDE)/*.xml; do ruby level_converter.rb "$f"; done
```

edit: must be im not that clear with the question, so i've rephrased it

Regards,
Igor

Comment: One easy way to not change the files twice is to have some naming convention for the original files like original_1.xml, original_2.xml and the created files can be created_1.xml etc. Interesting problem.

Comment: not essentially - xcode puts stuff to some distribution/deployment platform folder, and if these files are changed there - there should be no issues. The question is what exactly that folder is, it should be some environment variable or smth

Comment: could please the person that marked my question -1 explain why? Is it the way i asked that you displiked, or is it just what i want to do not just looking right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to achieve what i wanted, here is the script:

```
PROJ_DIR=${PWD}

echo "Converting xml files..."
for f in "${CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH}/"*.xml
do
    cp $PROJ_DIR/Resources/"${f##*/}" "$f"
    ruby level_converter.rb "$f" $PROJ_DIR/key_hash;
done

exit 0;
```

So i used this ${CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH} variable.

explanation:

- the for iterates the *.xml files in the destination directory
- cp $PROJ_DIR/Resources/"${f##*/}" "$f": as far as xcode only copies resources only if they were changed i have to manually copy the xml files to prevent them being converted more then once - so the converter is executed each build and so it should have original files in place to convert
- ruby level_converter.rb "$f" $PROJ_DIR/key_hash; : this simply executes the script

this does what i wan't but there are drawbacks/doubts:

- from time to time i get a warning that the signed resources where changed or removed (well that doesn't surprise me though). Maybe there is a way to supress this? It does stop the app being sandboxed and i have to build again and hope there will be no warning next time. Lucky me it does not appear often
- building takes much longer, it would still be nice to figure if the original files where changed and only execute the script if necessary
- i still think there should be some "proper" way to achieve what i wanted
- i am not sure i've picked up the variable CODESIGNING_FOLDER_PATH correctly, maybe i should use another one

edit: i moved the run script to be run before compiling source code, and didn't get any warnings about signed resources changed since then. Wandering if that's the cause